# PHP RSS XML parse, filter and display again

Tags: php, xml, rss

I am loading a RSS XML feed in PHP with `DOMDocument`. That works fine. I need to parse my XML, find specific values and then only display certain nodes again.

The XML looks like that...

```
<rss version="2.0">
  <channel>
  <title>Title</title>
  <link></link>
  <item>
    <title>Title #1</title>
    <description>Here I want to filter</description>
  </item>
  <item>
    <title>Title #2</title>
    <description>Should not be displayed</description>
  </item>
</channel>
```

I want to search inside the description tag, and if a keyword has been found I want to display the `item`. If it is not found, I want to delete the parent `item`.

That is what I tried so far...

```
<?php

header('Content-Type: text/xml');

// Load our XML document
$rss = new DOMDocument();
$rss->load('https://myurl');

$description = $rss->getElementsByTagName('description');

foreach ($description as $node) {
    $s = $node->nodeValue;

    if (strpos($s, 'filter') !== false)
    {
      //found the keyword, nothing to delete
    }
    else
    {
      //didnt find it, now delete item
      $node->parentNode->parentNode->removeChild($node->parentNode);
    }
}

echo $description->saveXml();
```

I am trying to get all description nodes, check if they contain the string and if not, delete the parent. The searching for the String works, however deleting the node not. If I echo my XML, nothing has changed.

Comment: In your sample XML, both items contain `filter` so neither will be deleted.

Comment: @NigelRen Thats correct. I just changed that to demonstrate the question. In my example it is still not working eventhough only certain nodes have it.

Comment: At the end you should use `echo $rss->saveXml();`.

Comment: @NigelRen Tried it, but still shows the XML. I think getElementsByTagName is wrong. It returns a int, not the node. The For Loop is only run once

Comment: With your test XML (although corrected to add the end rss tag), it does as I would expect and displays only the first item, removing the `Should not be displayed` item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getElementsByTagName()` will return a "live" result. It will change if you modify the document. You could use `iterator_to_array()` to make a stable copy.

Another option is to use Xpath expressions to fetch specific nodes.

```
$document = new DOMDocument();
$document->loadXML($xmlString);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($document);

// fetch items that contain "filter" in their description
$items = $xpath->evaluate('/rss/channel/item[contains(description, "filter")]');
foreach ($items as $item) {
    // dump the title child element text content
    var_dump($xpath->evaluate('string(title)', $item));
} 

// fetch items that do not contain "filter" in their description
$items = $xpath->evaluate('/rss/channel/item[not(contains(description, "filter"))]');
foreach ($items as $item) {
    // remove item element
    $item->parentNode->removeChild($item);
} 
echo $document->saveXML();
```

Output:

```
string(8) "Title #1"
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<rss version="2.0">
  <channel>
  <title>Title</title>
  <link/>
  <item>
    <title>Title #1</title>
    <description>Here I want to filter</description>
  </item>

</channel>
</rss>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! XPath worked perfectly. I removed the var_dump, because XML gave an issue when displaying it.

Comment: Of course, these are two examples - one how to show data from certain nodes and the other how to remove specific nodes.

Comment: Got it! Thank you so much for your help!! Appreciated